# Example of holomorphic function $f$ such that $\lim_{|\zeta|\rightarrow z}\text{Im}f(\zeta) = arg(z)$

Tags: complex-analysis, holomorphic-functions, analytic-functions

This question came up in a recent qualifying exam.

> Prove that there exists a holomorphic function $f : D(0,1) \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ such that 
>   $$\lim_{\zeta \rightarrow z}\text{Im}\ f(\zeta) = \text{Arg}(z)$$ 
>   for all $z \in \{\omega : |\omega| = 1\} \setminus \{-1\}$, where $\text{Arg}(z) \in (-\pi, \pi)$.

I'm really stuck on this one, so any help would be appreciated.

UPDATE: Following votes and comments that this question is "off-topic" or just "not a good question", let me be more specific about what I am asking:

> Can you provide an explicit construction of such a function?

That is my question.

Comment: the question is weird, the answer is using the Cauchy integral formula

Comment: @user1952009 $log(e^{i\theta})$, but $log$ is not holomorphic on $D(0,1)$. That's where I'm stuck

Comment: @user1952009 can you elaborate?

Comment: if $f$ is real on $|z| = 1$, what is the real part of $g(a) = \frac{1}{2 i \pi}\int_{|z| = 1} \frac{f(z)}{z-a}dz$ as $a \to e^{i t}$ ? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_kernel

Comment: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Answer (score 0):

Following the comment by @user1952009...

If we define $g(z) := \text{Arg}(z)$ for $z \in \partial D(0,1)$, where $\text{Arg}(z) \in (-\pi, \pi]$, then $g$ is continouous for all $z \in \partial D(0,1)\setminus \{-1\}$. It follows that
$$ u(z) := \left\{ \begin{array}{cl} 
\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} g(e^{i\theta})\cdot \dfrac{1 - |z|^{2}}{|z - e^{i\theta}|^{2}} d\theta & \text{ if } z \in D(0,1) \\
g(z) & \text{ if } z \in \partial D(0,1)
\end{array} \right. $$
is harmonic on $D(0,1)$ and continuous on $\overline{D(0,1)}\setminus \{-1\}$.

> For a proof of this claim, see *Function Theory of One Complex Variable* by Krantz & Green, page 213. Note that in the proof they assume the function $g$ is continuous for all $z \in \partial D(0,1)$, but the same steps apply.

So, we have that $u$ is harmonic on $D(0,1)$ and therefore there exists a holomorphic function $f$ on $D(0,1)$ such that $\text{Im}\ f = u$.